# What's the best practice for placement of settings menu in a webapp or website?

Tags: usability, navigation, menu, user-centered-design, settings

I was wondering is there any reason behind placing "settings" alongside other menu items and placing it inside profile or some other menu? Can anyone tell me what's the difference?

Comment: I think that there is a difference between "user settings", "global application settings" and "admin settings".  There is sure easier to manage if all resides in one place "Settings" at a modul level.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from ease of use and accessibility. Websites usually place settings in proximity to other user options like profile, and edit options.
You can't place it in the nav, or the bottom !